# Org Shape Permissions Missing from Permission Set Setup

Tags: permission-sets, org-shape

I am trying to follow this Salesforce DX Developer Guide:

- [Org Shape Permissions (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_permissions.htm)

I have created a `Permission Set` and I want to add the two permissions:

1. Create and manage org shapes: `Object Settings > Shape Representation > Create, Delete`
2. Use an org shape to create a scratch org:`Object Settings > Shape Representation > Read, View All`

But I cannot seem to find them anywhere.

I have the `Dev Hub` enabled in my production org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to also enable `Org Shape for Scratch Orgs` in my production org (which contains the Dev Hub) so the `Shape Representation` object appeared inside `Object Settings`